# CentOSでのTrema(0.10.1)の実行時のエラーについて

Tags: ruby, centos

[TremaでOpenFlowプログラミング](https://yasuhito.github.io/trema-book/)

上記サイトを参考にTremaのインストールを終え、実行すると以下のようなエラーが出ました。
`command.rb`を色々いじってみても結果は変わらず分かりません。お助け頂けると嬉しいです。
環境は、CentOS 7です。

```
[root@localhost hello_trema]# ./bin/trema run ./lib/hello_trema.rb -c trema.conf
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/trema-0.10.1/lib/trema/command.rb:153:in `create_pid_file': HelloTrema is already running. (RuntimeError)
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/trema-0.10.1/lib/trema/command.rb:29:in `run'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/trema-0.10.1/bin/trema:68:in `block (2 levels) in <module:App>'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gli-2.13.4/lib/gli/command_support.rb:126:in `call'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gli-2.13.4/lib/gli/command_support.rb:126:in `execute'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gli-2.13.4/lib/gli/app_support.rb:296:in `block in call_command'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gli-2.13.4/lib/gli/app_support.rb:309:in `call'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gli-2.13.4/lib/gli/app_support.rb:309:in `call_command'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gli-2.13.4/lib/gli/app_support.rb:83:in `run'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/trema-0.10.1/bin/trema:291:in `<module:App>'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/trema-0.10.1/bin/trema:14:in `<module:Trema>'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/trema-0.10.1/bin/trema:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./bin/trema:29:in `load'
    from ./bin/trema:29:in `<main>'
```

Comment: 「HelloTrema is already running. (RuntimeError)」というメッセージですから、（１）HelloTremaというプログラムは実行されている、（２）同じ名前のプログラムは実行できないのに、(たぶん、同じ設定のまま)再度HelloTremaのプログラムの実行したものだから、「もう、走ってますよぉ」という警告が表示されたという事ではないでしょうか。

Comment: プログラムが実行されているというよりは、pid_fileが既に存在しているのが問題だったようです。コメントありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

[terma/command.rb](https://github.com/trema/trema/blob/0.10.1/lib/trema/command.rb#L153) のソースを見るかぎり、`FileTest.exists? pid_file`が `true`のため、例外が発生しているようです。
`command.rb`を直接触れるのであれば、例えば、153行目を以下のように修正して実行してください。

```
puts "DEBUG: #{pid_file}"
raise "#{name} is already running." if running?
```

実行すると、ターミナルに、`pid_file`のパスが出力されると思いますので、
pid_fileが存在しないか確認してください。存在するようであれば、削除してから再実行してください。

ただ、`pid_file`は一時ディレクトリ内にあるはずなので、通常は、起動毎に変るはずなのですが。いずれにしても、デバッグプリントを入れてみることで切り分けができると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。DEBUGを用いて、pid_fileを削除した後実行すると以下の様に再びエラーが発生しました。 [root@localhost hello_trema]# rm -rf /tmp/HelloTrema.pid
[root@localhost hello_trema]# ./bin/trema run ./lib/hello_trema.rb -c trema.conf
DEBUG: /tmp/HelloTrema.pid
ovs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
error: Open vSwitch (dpid = 2748) is already running!

Comment: 無事解決できました。ありがとうございました。